# type narrowing in ternary

Tags: arrays, typescript, narrowing

In `myFunction` below, I accept a parameter which is either a string or an array of strings, and I normalize it to an array in the function body:

```
export const myFunction = <T extends string | string[]>(
  myParam: T
) => {
  let myStringArray = (Array.isArray(myParam) ? myParam : [myParam])
}
```

I expected `Array.isArray` to narrow the type in the branches of the ternary operator to either `string` or `string[]` so that the final type of `myStringArray` would be `string[]`. Instead, the final type is more complicated: `(T & any[]) | T[]`.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLYE8BiBXZBGASxTgF44AeAFTlBmGQBNU50pjkBzOAH3YxOPANoBdAHwAKAFBw42AAoBDKMowAuODRkBKChLgBvOXAA2wTFgDKQrtwCCUNVgpwpTlwDpiqT8qwpJVV1fQB+BSwVNQw4LRFgmLFdGQBfGSA)

I noticed, however, that if I restrucure the code to use an if-else instead, the type-narrowing works perfectly:

```
export const myFunction = <T extends string | string[]>(
  myParam: T
) => {
  let myStringArray;
  if (Array.isArray(myParam)) {
    myStringArray = myParam;
  } else {
    myStringArray = [myParam];
  } 
  console.log(myStringArray);
}
```

The type of `myStringArray` on the last line is `string[]`, as expected.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLYE8BiBXZBGASxTgF44AeAFTlBmGQBNU50pjkBzOAH3YxOPANoBdAHwAKAFBw42AAoBDKMowAuODRkBKChLgBvOXAA2wTFgDKQrtwCCUNVgDcp4gDM4Upy4B0xKh+ylhSSqrquvom8vLYtsKOzqEUClgqahju8gC+9GaowMam8TZ2PCFYaSIRWWI5cPmmSGgQFv5mENzh5UlVuu65MkA)

Is it possible to get the type-narrowing to work with the ternary operator? Are the two expressions not equivalent?

Comment: Feels like a bug

Comment: I built out a small project and can verify this behavior ..  Odd -- I agree with @TitianCernicova-Dragomir -- You may want to visit the [GIT Page](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript) page and submit a bug report.  At least if it's not a bug, you may get an explanation as to "why"

Comment: seems like it has to do with the generic. If you change `myParam` to just `string | string[]` the narrowing seems to work as expected. Seems like it's because `Array.isArray` narrows to `any[]`, so it ends up as `T & any[]`. What if you used your own typeguard w/ better typing?

Comment: Seems like it's working to me though. Who's to say it's safe to narrow `T` using `Array.isArray`? `T` isn't `string | string[]` it's just some type that's assignable to that. Could be an array-like object too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TS compiler does not evaluate the logic of ternary expressions when producing a return type.

For a simpler example:

```
const x = true ? 1 : 0 // TS says 1 | 0
```

Despite the `0` value being impossible, TS does not discard it.

The only analysis TS performs on ternary expressions is type refinement *within* them:

[image]
[image]
[image]

This has been previously reported as marked as working as intended: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39550